# JavaConfig without being dependent on Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Java added official dependency injection support with things like `@Inject`, `@Named`, and other in [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330). These can be used with different frameworks like Spring or Guice.

Spring also offers a [JavaConfig and Annotation-Driven Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html), such as using `@Configuration` and `@Import` as an alternative to an XML configuration.

My question is, are there ways to accomplish the same application configuration usingannotations and JavaConfig without having to depend on Spring?

Comment: Are you asking about using `@Configuration` specifically to register beans for injection, or are you asking more generally if there are equivalent alternatives?

Comment: More generally if there are other alternatives, and if Java has its own version. My main thinking is that if I wanted to use some annotation based JavaConfig for applications and in the future I wanted to change to a different DI framework (Spring or Guice or Dagger or something else), what are my options?

Comment: Supplying the beans to be injected is generally framework-specific; for example, if you're using Guide, you'll write modules. `@Configuration` is a Spring thing, as is the older `@Autowired` annotation. `@Inject` is an equivalent (which Spring also recognizes) that works across frameworks.

Comment: That's kind of what it seemed like looking through Guice/Spring, wasn't sure if there were additional shared components that really tied it all together and made it easy to just plugin. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: At last you have to tie your non framework specific code to a framework, otherwise the framework classes won't load... I think framework-neutral is useful in multi-module projects in witch each team maintains a module and teams providing bean libraries don't have to know about the DI framework their client teams are using, or the client teams can change the DI framework relatively easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way to do this, as you have to have some way to tie in the non-framework specific code to the framework. [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) provides good support for dependency injection, but you still need some way to tie it into the framework whether that is using Spring's `@Configuration` or Guice modules.